# Sum operation on documents with different structures

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I'm trying to use the aggregation pipeline to be able to do a report table with (sort,paging, etc) using mongodb for my back end. I run into a problem that my schema is not the same but i need to add all the values. I was trying to use the unwind command but it only works in arrays so run out of alternatives.

**Sample Documents**

```
{
  "_id": "first",
  "apple": 6,
  "pears": 7,
  "total_fruits": "13"
},

{
  "_id": "second",
  "apple": 6,
  "bananas": 2,
  "total_fruits": "8"
}
```

**Desired Result**

```
{
  "_id": "result",
  "apple": 12,
  "pears": 7,
  "bananas": 2,
  "total_fruits": "21"
}
```

Comment: Do you know all the fields' name in your collection or they are dynamics?

Comment: If you could use an schema like `{ "_id":"first", fruits: [{name: "apple", count: 6}, {name: "pears", count: 7}], "total_fruits":13 }`, then your pipeline would be way easier to write

Comment: @Styvane the fields are dynamic. That is why is difficult.

Comment: @AliDehghani I would have to add a step in the processing to do that but might be an option.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of aggregating, why not use `mapReduce()`?

```
function sumKeyFromCollection(collectionName, keyName) {
    map = function() { emit(keyName, this[keyName]); }
    red = function(k, v) {
      var i, sum = 0;
      for (i in v) {
        sum += v[i];
      }
      return sum;
    }
    return db[collectionName].mapReduce(map, red, {out : {inline: 1}});
}
```

For your example documents:

```
{
  "_id": "first",
  "apple": 6,
  "pears": 7,
  "total_fruits": "13"
},
{
  "_id": "second",
  "apple": 6,
  "bananas": 2,
  "total_fruits": "8"
}
```

You could call the function on each field name:

```
console.log(sumKeyFromCollection("collectionName", "apple"));
> { "_id": "...", "apple": 12 }
```

Then use each of them to produce your resultant document:

```
var fruits = [ "apple", "bananas", "total_fruits" ];
var results = []; 

for (var i = 0; i < fruits.length; i++) {
  results.push(sumKeyFromCollection("collectionName", fruits[i]));
}
```

**EDIT** Also, to get every field name in a collection programmatically:

```
function getAllCollectionFieldNames(collectionName) {
    mr = db.runCommand({
      "mapreduce" : collectionName,
      "map" : function() {
        for (var key in this) { emit(key, null); }
      },
      "reduce" : function(key, stuff) { return null; }, 
      "out": "my_collection" + "_keys"
    });
    db[mr.result].distinct("_id");
}
```

Which returns an array of unique field names (even if they only appear in one document).

Comment: Something like this would work. The reason i'm looking for options with the pipeline is that due after the grouping i need to apply a sort / skip and limit.  

So right now holding the map reduce option to be a posibility  but exploring my options.